# Netlify mixed content error because of legacy image urls (Nuxt)

Tags: html, nuxt.js, netlify, mixed-content

I have a basic shop page displaying products and their images are broken due to **mixed content error** which occurs because the provider of the images uses only HTTP as it is a legacy database.

I want to display the images like so:

```
<img :src="cardData.image"/>
```

I've tried using
`<meta http-equiv:'Content-Security-Policy' content:'upgrade-insecure-requests'/>`
without any luck.

Does Netlify provide a way to avoid having to use HTTPS?

I am of course unable to modify the legacy site as it is owned by another company.

Comment: What is the issue with having both HTTPS and HTTP? Does it say something blocking?

Comment: What I mean by that: if your website do have mixed content, it will display a warning and start alarming the users by the fact that the website is not "secure". But having HTTP everywhere or HTTP + some HTTPS will be as bad. Modern browsers will shame you either way. Do the images work if you search for access manually with the HTTPS prefix?